# Embed activity of application A inside application B's viewgroup in android

Tags: android, view, android-activity, embed, viewgroup

My requirement is as follows:

I have two of my application, one is Application A and Application B.
Now I want them to work individually as well as mutually 
We can assume this is the scenario which I need(assumed):

> Application A has activity DoPlusMinusActivity which is having two EditText box and two buttons named Add and subtract, which does the appropriate function as their name and store the result.
>
> Application B has activity MultipleCalcActivity which is having some EditText box and some buttons for the functions user wants to perform. Now there is a button which should open the DoPlusMinusActivity of Application A on the predefined area of current activity. 
>   It means any time I can touch the options of Application B.
>   User should be able to perform the calculation there and can found it in the Application B.
>
> The Application A's activity DoPlusMinusActivity should be opened on some part of calling application's activity, it should be touchable outside. We can understood it by using an example of a wood table having some glasses of water on the middle while a tray of cup of  tea on left side, so that any time user can pick the water glass or tea cup.

Suggest me, how could it be possible to achieve it? any kind of help would be appreciated.

Note: Both the applications are mine and it is sure that they are installed on the same device.
I can change the code of both application.

Comment: It is possible.. i am working on your question..

Comment: Here is my idea. You can call the activity explicitly.[link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html). But i still didnt understand the part where <"DoPlusMinusActivity should not cover the whole activity of Application B's Activity">

Comment: It means it should not cover it visually like a small rectangle on the bottom left corner of the big rectangle.

Comment: But y would it do that.. when u call the activity, the called activity covers the entire screen. Am i not right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32125/discussion-between-amalbit-and-skygeek)

Comment: Nope, it is not possible to come on chat for me

Comment: It breaks my office rulez!!